# Flatmapping on an option value

Tags: scala

Why exactly does the flatMap not work in this case, can someone please detail what is going on.

```
val o: Option[Int] = Some(1)
o.map(o => println(o))
>> 1

o.flatMap(o => println(o))
>><console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Option[?]
       o.flatMap(o => println(o))
```

Comment: Because it wants an `Option` but finds a `Unit`. What exactly is unclear about it?

Comment: @Dima I guess the fact that flatMap requires and Option, the reasoning behind it.  I thought a flatMap removes options...

Comment: You can say that it removes options, yes. That's the reason it requires them!  You can't remove something you don't have ... You give it a function returning an Option, and it "removes" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically, and not trying to be 100% correct, but more trying to give a nice overview, you have:

- collections (like Lists and Sets) and some other containers (like Option) have a `map` method that is applied to the elements inside (in case of the list it transforms every element using the function you provide. in case of the Option, is transforms the only element using the function you provide)
- collections and (some) containers also have a `flat`/`flatten` method which flats a nested collection (List of Lists to a List with all elements, or Option of Option to Option)
- flatmap is a map followed by a flatten. in order to use it, your map function/transformation must return a collection/container

while not 100% correct, it should be enough to get you started and understand :)

Answer (score 2):

> I guess the fact that `flatMap` requires an `Option`, the reasoning behind it.

This is not really a question that one asks about highly polymorphic functions. It is what it is, that's just the definition of `flatMap` on `Option`.

All of these `flatMap` methods in the Scala API are consistent in that they correspond roughly to the Haskell function `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` in [`Control.Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html).

There are methods that do the thing you want (`foreach`), but they're different methods with different names and different types.

Answer (score 1):

Because `println` returns `Unit` and not a new instance of `Option[T]`. Flatmap is used to transform a value (if present) and map it to a new `Option[T]`.

What you are doing with `println` can be accomplished with:

```
o.foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think one should really just follow function signatures.

In this case it can be found [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Option@flatMap[B](f:A=%3EOption[B]):Option[B]).

It says `def flatMap[B](f: (A) ⇒ Option[B]): Option[B]`

But the `f` you're passing has a different signature.
Specifically `def println(x: Any): Unit`